# How to handle onTouchEvent UP on orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity

I have implmeneted a custom View component that extends from ViewGroup. I have overriden the `onTouchEvent` method to listen for MotionEvent events. What I basically will do is, if the user toches and releases my custom view with his finger (`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`) the activity containing my View will finish. My custom View has a reference to the activity.

So far so good, the only problem I have is on orientation changes, with the following scenario:

1. User touches my view (finger on my view)
2. User rotates the device (finger is still on my view)
3. A `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` will be recognized, caused by the orientation change and the recreation of the new Activity (orientation change will recreate a rotated activity)
4. Since I call activity.finish() while handling a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` a IllegalStateException will be thrown because the old activity has already been destroyed and than I call finish() again (while handling MotionEvent).

Any idea how to handle this problem. I have tried to use `onDetachFromWindow` but that seems to be to late. Is there another method / callback that I can use. I would like to make a small library for my view, therefore I do not want to use `Activity.onDestroy()` because I would like to avoid to call a method of my view, to inform that the activity has been destroyed.

Since API Level 17 there is a method `Activity.isDestroyed()`. That would be the solution to fix my problem, but I must support older versions (back to Android 8) too. `Activity.isFinishing()` would work, but I would like to have covered the more general case when the activity has been destroyed (since the user of my library could implement its own ACTION_UP Callback where he could call `Activity.onBackPressed()` instead of calling `Activity.finished()`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

in your manifest, you can set your activity like so:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
              android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```

This tells Android you'll handle rotation changes yourself and it won't destroy your activity.  If you really need to handle rotation while touching, I have no answer :(